# AWS Dynamodb and Availability Zone underlying architecture

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am learning AWS Dynamodb. As AWS document, it is set up and configured as a distributed database cluster by AWS, and data in DB be across the availability zones in an AWS region for failover.

I really want to understand the underlying architecture of Dynamodb and Availability Zone.

As my thought, *there are multiple server instances(maybe EC2 instance) as a db cluster in an availability zone as DynamoDB; the dynamodb in a availability zone will be replicated across all availability zones in a region*.

Any idea or discussion or helpful link is welcome.

Answer (score 9):

It is a bit vague to me what is your actual question, but I'll try to answer what I think is the core of your question - what do "availability zones" do. I'm leaving out a lot of details on DynamoDB's leader model and consistency, which isn't really pertinent to your question about availability zones. You can find these and other issues explained in many documents, presentations and videos - one of my favorites is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvBR71D0nAQ.

Anyway, each piece of data in DynamoDB is replicated to three physical nodes (machines). DynamoDB's cluster may actually have hundreds of these nodes (you have no way to tell), but each item of data is stored on exactly three of them. You don't know which, but something you do know is that two items in the same *partition* (i.e., have the same partition key) are guaranteed to be on the same three nodes - this allows an operation ("Query") to read an entire partition to be efficient as it can read contiguously from the disk of one node.

Anyway, this replication provides two main guarantees: it provides **durability** - meaning that if one copy gets lost, we still have other copies. And it provides **high-availability** - meaning that if one copy is temporarily down (e.g., power outage, network problem, etc.) the database is still fully operational - both reads and writes can proceed without waiting for the missing copy to reemerge.

The problem is that if all three copies live sit inside the same data center, disaster can strike all three at the same time: A fire in the datacenter can cause loss of **durability** (all three copies go up in smoke, literally). A power outage or network problem at this datacenter can cause loss of **high-availability**. To solve this Amazon has in each geographic region several **separate datacenters**, which it calls "availability zones". These separate data centers sit in physically different  buildings, connected to different power grids, different Internet connection points, etc., to guarantee as much as possible that one disaster cannot effect more than one of these datacenters. The data centers are located physically such that they are near enough to each other so that network latency between them is minimal (e.g., 1ms), yet far enough from each other so that a single disaster is unlikely to hit both.

DynamoDB guarantees that the three copies of each item of data don't just end up in the same availability zone (data center) - but go to three different ones. At least in Regions which have three or more availability zones (most do).

Even with separate availability zones, some huge disasters may still strike several of them. You can find many ideas for such disasters in movies, involving an all-out nuclear war, alien invasion, an asteroid, a tsunami taking out the entire eastern seaboard ;-) For these and other less Hollywoodic reasons, Amazon also gives you the option of multiple geographical **regions**, which place copies of your data in completely different countries and continents. But because of the high latency between these copies, it changes a lot in how this replication works (check out "global tables" in DynamoDB's documention), and this is really the topic for a different discussion.

Comment: Appreciate your such detail answer, very helpful for me.